# Data Retrieval in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to retrieve some data from a table where the age is in a certain range.

## EXAMPLE

Persons with age from 20 to 30 years. How can I do it? I tried with the following query, but I was unable to get it.

```
$age="SELECT * 
    From    rec_patient_reg
    WHERE   p_age  >='$afrom' <= '$to'";
    $result1=mysql_query($age) 
    or die(mysql_error());
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    echo "<b>Patient ID</b> = " .$result["Patient_id"] . " <br>";
    echo "<b>NAME</b> = ".$result["p_fname"]."<br><br>----------------<br><br>";
```

Please help me.

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: no error message but the retirived values are not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you are not getting any error message since you are using mysql. Take a look at this example below,

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  Age  >= 20 <= 25
```

This is not allowed on any other RDBMS but MySQL allows it. What it does is it implictly allows boolean expression on the rightmost side of the filter, eg

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  (Age  >= 20) <= 25
```

So in this case, the value is now parsed into (*let's say Age = 5*)

```
WHERE  0  >= 25
```

causing you to retrieve unexpected result.

---

You can use `BETWEEN` if you want to search for ranges,

```
SELECT * 
From    rec_patient_reg
WHERE   p_age  BETWEEN '$afrom' AND '$to'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Will you let us answer 1 SQL question? :p

Comment: @Mr.Alien you are still allowed to answer all of it :p

Comment: i have lot of queries, i done with mysql_* functions? should i change everything for my site? no other way to give security?

Comment: @praveenrsmart it will soon be deprecated. If the site is already huge and curently up then leave it as it. or it's up to you `:)`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rec_patient_reg`
WHERE `p_age` BETWEEN '$afrom' AND '$to'
```

Comment: i have lot of queries, i done with mysql_* functions? should i change everything for my site? no other way to give security?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
$age = "SELECT * FROM rec_patient_reg WHERE p_age  >='$afrom' AND p_age <= '$to'";
```